# SQL Server stored procedure which will include insert of number based on another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

What I'm trying to achieve is I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewCarouselImage
     (@sliderid int, 
      @caption varchar(250), 
      @imageUrl varchar(150), 
      @imageOrder int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblItems(sliderid, caption, imageUrl, imageOrder, isActive)
    VALUES(@sliderid, @caption, @imageUrl)
END
GO
```

In the `imageOrder` column, I want to insert the value of the last `imageOrder` for that `sliderid + 1`. So I'll need something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 imageOrder 
FROM tblItems 
WHERE sliderid = @sliderid 
ORDER BY imageOrder DESC
```

For the value I selected I want to increment that one + 1 and use that in the insert stored procedure.

Is it possible that to be done without multiple SQL queries from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblItems (sliderid, caption, imageUrl, imageOrder, isActive)
SELECT TOP 1 @sliderid, @caption, @imageUrl, imageOrder + 1, ????
FROM tblItems 
WHERE sliderid = @sliderid 
order by imageOrder desc
```

You will need to specify a value for `isActive`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblItems(sliderid, caption, imageUrl, imageOrder, isActive)
SELECT TOP 1 @sliderid, @caption, imageOrder 
FROM tblItems 
WHERE sliderid = @sliderid 
ORDER BY imageOrder DESC
```

As noted by the other answerer, your columns didn't quite match up.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give a full schema view of what your doing, but you are using SQL 2012, so you could instead of managing your own incrementing values, create a [sequence][1] potentially instead.

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx CREATE SEQUENCE